# batch for loop file search

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop

```
@ECHO OFF 
SET driveLetter=%~d0
FOR /R %%x IN (*.pst) DO (
    ROBOCOPY %%x %driveLetter%\%%x /E /COPYALL /ZB /MT:20 /XJ /R:2 /W:5
)
PAUSE
EXIT
```

I can't get this working. What I want to do is search the user folder (incl. subfolders) for any .pst files and then copy these to a flash drive.

Comment: I will give you a hint.  What do you think these variables **%driveLetter%\%%x** expand to.  You may want to consider using quotes around your file paths as well.

Comment: Drive of the script and %%x

Comment: So an example of that would be?  When you see those variables expand it should be plain as day as to what you are doing wrong. Put an echo in front of the ROBOCOPY cmd so you can see what that line of code is really doing.

Comment: are you not wanting to `RoboCopy "%%x"` to `"%driveLetter%\%%~nxx"`?

Comment: I ask because otherwise you'd surely be doing something like this: `@RoboCopy "%CD%" "%~d0" *.pst /S /COPYALL /ZB /MT:20 /XJ /R:2 /W:5`.

Comment: Hi, I want to copy (ex. C:\Users\USER\Local\AppData\Microsoft\Office\15\*.pst) to %~d0 (on a flash drive) without specifying the path.
The line above copies from C:\Windows\system32\

Comment: Change your Current Directory to suit

Comment: If you're only copying from the logged in user then replace `"%CD%"` with `"%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Outlook"` however, it was my understanding that those files in newer versions of Outlook are stored in `"%UserProfile%\Documents\Outlook Files"` so I'd suggest you replace `"%CD%"` with `"%UserProfile%"` to cover both options, _(although it would take longer)_.

Comment: `%%x` expands to a full path including the drive when you use the [`/R` option of `for`](http://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html), so the destination path is invalid. I do not get the purpose of the loop as [`robocopy /E`](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html) processes sub-directories anyway...

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple actually just use xcopy:

```
xcopy c:\users\%username%\*.pst F:\ /e
```

(replace F:/ with drive location if its not F).

Comment: Not quite what I'm looking for. I want to search a variable directory and copy whatever .pst files may reside to a flash drive (again different drive letters).

Comment: In my comment I changed **`/E`** to **`/S`** for a reason, empty directories cannot contain a **`.pst`** file. My guess is also that they don't know the user names, they want the pst files from all users, so **`%SystemDrive%\Users`** would be a better place to recurse from.

Comment: Good point especially %SYSTEMDRIVE%, but I still can't get this to work:

`@ECHO OFF 
SET driveLetter=%~d0
ROBOCOPY "%SYSTEMDRIVE\Users" "%~d0" *.pst /S /COPYALL /ZB /XJ /MT:20 /R:2 /W:5
PAUSE
EXIT`

Just returns  src: C:\WINDOWS\system32\~d0\ dst: BLANK

Destination should be E:\ (USB)

I'm probably missing something

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF 
SET driveLetter=%~d0
ROBOCOPY %USERPROFILE% %driveLetter%\Outlook *.pst /S /COPYALL /ZB /XJ /MT:20 /R:2 /W:5
PAUSE
EXIT
```

Solution. Thanks to everybody.